# How do you properly implement (C++) thread local storage in a dynamically loaded DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll, thread-local-storage

In this case my dynamically loaded DLL is loaded by Windows Explorer in order to add a new propertysheet (new tab) to the file/folder properties page.

A simple example of this is StrmExt.dll ([download source](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6943EB-790A-44AA-B32D-14ED7E22FD5D/NTFSExt.exe)). In this example (source provided by Microsoft) the DLL does NOT use thread local storage (TLS) and therefore causes major problems when loading multiple property pages at the same time.

Upon reviewing the source the DLL required one thread-base variable (the file path of the file)...

```
static TCHAR g_szFile[MAX_PATH];
```

Changing this one line of code to:

```
_declspec (thread) TCHAR g_szFile[MAX_PATH];
```

... Enabled the DLL to support multiple threads and therefore multiple instances of the propertysheet. However, I knew this change would only be supported by Windows Vista and newer (tests on Windows 7 have been very positive). XP, for example, would not support this for a dynamically loaded library... And it is [known to crash the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s9wt68x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). (See final paragraph).

In order to run on XP I could not use this declaration. I suspected I needed to enhanced their DLL entry point from:

```
extern "C"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID /*lpReserved*/)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _Module.Init(ObjectMap, hInstance, &LIBID_STRMEXTLib);
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
        _Module.Term();
    return TRUE;    // ok
}
```

...to something like this... As previously seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2114/Simplify-the-Use-of-Thread-Local-Storage)

```
struct ThreadData {
    static TCHAR g_szFile[MAX_PATH];
};
...
DWORD g_dwThreadIndex;

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                      DWORD dwReason, LPVOID /*pReserved*/)
{
    ThreadData* pData;   
    switch (dwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

            g_dwThreadIndex = ::TlsAlloc();
            if (g_dwThreadIndex == TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES)
                return FALSE;

           // execute the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH code

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:

            // allocate memory for this thread
            pData = (ThreadData*) ::LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(ThreadData));
            if (pData == 0)
                return FALSE;

            ::TlsSetValue(g_dwThreadIndex, (LPVOID) pData);
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:

            // release memory for this thread
            pData = (ThreadData*) ::TlsGetValue(g_dwThreadIndex);
            if (pData != 0)
                ::LocalFree((HLOCAL) pData);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

            // release memory for this thread
            pData = (ThreadData*) ::TlsGetValue(g_dwThreadIndex);
            if (pData != 0)
                ::LocalFree((HLOCAL) pData);
            // release the TLS index
            ::TlsFree(g_dwThreadIndex);
            break;
    } 
    return TRUE;
}
```

This works fine during the first load of the DLL whether I create 1 or 2 threads. After the DLL is freed Explorer crashes on the next load of the library.

What am I misunderstanding? I noticed the original developer purposely disabled thread notification upon the DLL process attach notification. Why?

```
DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInstance);
```

Comment: DisableThreadLibraryCalls is just an optimization.  "Explorer crashes" is not an appropriate problem description, you'll have to document the crash details better.

Comment: Fair comments.  I knew about it being an optimization option, but was curious if there is another reason it was there.  The XP system I have this on is currently in a VM on another system and I'll see about providing an exception report another day.  However, I am questioning the notification code in the example.  Does it look correct, especially in the context for Windows Explorer?  i.e. is the process attach logic correct in how it also executes the thread attach logic?  And, is the TLS properly freed on thread detach and process detach?

Comment: Clearly you have to remove the call to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` in order to receive `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` and `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. Other than that I guess you may have some leaks due to the vagaries of DllMain.

Comment: "I had a problem with a global variable so I used TLS and now I've got two problems."  Lose the global variable and you won't have a problem.

Comment: I don't think you're even guaranteed that you'll have one thread per property sheet. Lose the TLS; store the data in `PROPSHEETPAG::lParam`. It exists for a reason.

Comment: @MSalters I had previously tried the lParam with little success, hence the TLS approach.  However, your nudge got me back on track.  All sorted and working.  Thanks.  MSalters, put your comment into a answer and give it the green checkmark.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also see this article on things not to do in the DLLMain()  http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/12/03/dont-do-anything-in-dllmain-please/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the problem is best avoided at all. Yes, you'll probably have more threads than processes, and yes, each property sheet will be associated with only one thread, but the reverse is not guaranteed. Two property sheets may share a single thread, that's up to the OS.
(And such undocumented decisions change between versions).

Instead, use the `lParam` member of `PROPSHEETPAGE`. It's big enough to hold a pointer, also on 64 bits systems. Point that to your own class. Lifetime management is a lot simpler than the DLL attach/detach you were trying; Windows calls your [`PropSheetPageProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the right moment.

Comment: Thank you for directing me correctly. I now have a 32-bit and a 64-bit working DLL that appears to working on all Windows O/S versions, XP and beyond.